# How to offer custom domains for my Saas app in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, heroku

I want to offer custom domains for my clients in heroku.

Having my domain, www.xpto.com, and my users domains, user1.xpto.com, user2.xpto.com, I want to give them the possibility to add a CNAME record pointing to my app. A custom domain www.user1xpto.com pointing to user1.xpto.com.

How can I achieve this with Heroku?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with Heroku. If the user owns the domain, then they'll have to add a CNAME record themselves using their DNS provider to redirect it somewhere else. Nobody can come along and redirect *my* domain to your site, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add one of the [custom domain](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) add-ons to your app, you should be able to do this using the Heroku gem.

```
class CustomDomain < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    after_create :setup_at_heroku
    def setup_at_heroku
       # make calls with heroku gem here
       test_cname_later
    end
    def test_cname_later
      # use background job here to try to call custom.com/custom_domains/activate
    end
end
```

Setup an action to /custom_domains/activate that looks up the domain from the request and sets it to active.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty well without using the Heroku gem, by using the [Heroku REST API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart) to add domains as your users configure them to use.

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku API supports custom domain names. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score -1):

You can have wildcard custom domains with the wildcard domains addon but if you want the user to be able to use their own domain you will have to use the heroku gem inside your app to add the domain to your applications custom domains.

Comment: What does this means? "you will have to use the heroku gem"? This is not a good answer.

Comment: You'll note that my answer was from over 2 years ago that was WAAAAY before Heroku made their Rest API public, 2 years ago the only option was to include the Heroku gem inside your application.

Comment: I'm not saying my answer is better than you or that using the REST API is better than the Heroku gem, I'm just saying that your answer doesn't answer the question, it just mentions some obscure "Heroku gem" nobody has to know what is.